# Can't find the wxPython module

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to use wxPython module:

```
import wxPython
verw = 0.1
print("test con v", verw)
```

but in the result I get this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-387a974d6a30> in <module>
      1 
----> 2 import wxPython
      3 
      4 
      5 verw = 0.1

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wxPython'
```

[image]

Comment: just import wx only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the module you should install is `wx` and not `wxpython`.

See docs: https://wxpython.org/pages/overview/

Answer (score 1):

You need to import **wx** only.

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
```